# How to have gsub handle multiple patterns and replacements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, twitter

A while ago I created a function in PHP to "twitterize" the text of tweets pulled via Twitter's API.

Here's what it looked like:

```php
function twitterize($tweet){
$patterns = array ( "/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/", 
                    "/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))@([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/",
                    "/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))#([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/");
$replacements = array ("<a href='\\0' target='_blank'>\\0</a>", "<a href='http://twitter.com/\\1' target='_blank'>\\0</a>", "<a href='http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1&src=hash' target='_blank'>\\0</a>");

return preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $tweet);

}
```

Now I'm a little stuck with Ruby's `gsub`, I tried:

```rb
def twitterize(text)
patterns = ["/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/", "/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))@([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/", "/(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))#([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/"]
replacements =  ["<a href='\\0' target='_blank'>\\0</a>",
                "<a href='http://twitter.com/\\1' target='_blank'>\\0</a>",
                "<a href='http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1&src=hash' target='_blank'>\\0</a>"]

return text.gsub(patterns, replacements)
end
```

Which obviously didn't work and returned an error:

```
No implicit conversion of Array into String
```

And after looking at the [Ruby documentation for `gsub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) and exploring a few of the examples they were providing, I still couldn't find a solution to my problem: How can I have `gsub` handle multiple patterns and multiple replacements at once?

Comment: anyone care to explain why you are downvoting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you can read from the docs, `gsub` **does not** handle multiple patterns and replacements at once. That's what causing your error, quite explicit otherwise (you can read that as "give me a String, not an Array!!1").

You can write that like this:

```
def twitterize(text)
  patterns = [/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/, /(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))@([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/, /(?<=^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.]))#([A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_]+)/]
  replacements =  ["<a href='\\0' target='_blank'>\\0</a>",
            "<a href='http://twitter.com/\\1' target='_blank'>\\0</a>",
            "<a href='http://twitter.com/search?q=\\1&src=hash' target='_blank'>\\0</a>"]

  patterns.each_with_index do |pattern, i|
    text.gsub!(pattern, replacements[i])
  end

  text
end
```

This can be refactored into more elegant rubyish code, but I think it'll do the job.

Comment: ok thanks, I'm really surprised gsub does not handle multiple patterns. I just thought I wasn't understanding the documentation properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was because you tried to use an array of replacements in the place of a string in the `gsub` function. Its syntax is:

```
text.gsub(matching_pattern,replacement_text)
```

You need to do something like this:

```
replaced_text = text.gsub(pattern1, replacement1)
replaced_text = replaced_text.gsub(pattern2, replacement2)
```

and so on, where the pattern 1 is one of your matching patterns and replacement is the replacement text you would like.

Comment: wow, first time ruby is letting me down compared to PHP. It will definitely work, thanks!