# How to replace multiple characters in string with special characters

Tags: regex, ruby

I have a question that is almost identical to "[Ruby gsub multiple characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650681/ruby-gsub-multiple-characters-in-string)".

However, my string contains special characters:

```
a = "<p>text</p> <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em>"
```

Using `/\w+/` doesn't work for me.
I tried many different combinations, but no luck.
What RegEx match should I enter below to make it work? I want to replace those matches wherever they are in the string.

By the way I am using Rails.

My desired matches are:

```
a.gsub({{WHAT REGEX EXP?}},
  "\r\n" => "",
  "<p>" => "",
  "</p>" => "\n\n",
  "<br />" => "\n",
  "<strong>" => "*",
  "</strong>" => "*",
  "<em>" => "_",
  "</em>" => "_",
  "<s>" => "~",
  "</s>" => "~",
  "<blockquote>" => ">",
  "</blockquote>" => ">",
  "&" => "&amp;",
  "<" => "&lt;",
  ">" => "&gt;"
)
```

Comment: It looks more like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423345/gsub-for-multiple-patterns-and-multiple-replacements) one.

Comment: @SebastianPalma, according to your link, you can't do multiple replacements with gsub, but you can. If you look at the link I provided, it does multiple replacements, but the regex handles characters only. I just need to handle any character.

Comment: If either answer was helpful please select the one that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in one go:

```
replacements = {
  "\r\n" => "",
  "<p>" => "",
  "</p>" => "\n\n",
  "<br />" => "\n",
  "<strong>" => "*",
  "</strong>" => "*",
  "<em>" => "_",
  "</em>" => "_",
  "<s>" => "~",
  "</s>" => "~",
  "<blockquote>" => ">",
  "</blockquote>" => ">",
  "&" => "&amp;",
  "<" => "&lt;",
  ">" => "&gt;"
}

keys = Regexp.union(replacements.keys)
a    = "<p>text</p> <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em>"

p a.gsub(keys, replacements) # => "text\n\n *bold* and _italic_"
```

This works so easily because `Regexp.union` does all the hard work (escaping the weird chars) for you.

Comment: very nicely done. Will be using this. I wonder which method works faster... I would compare benchmarks but I have no idea how to do that :)

Comment: Be sure to read the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags .

Comment: In regex long chains of alternatives, esp with a common prefix (in this case `<` or `<b`) are slow, because engine needs to check alternatives one by one. See number of steps in those examples: https://regex101.com/r/dqMPXH/1/, https://regex101.com/r/dqMPXH/2/ https://regex101.com/r/dqMPXH/3/

Answer (score 2):

`#gsub` works:

```rb
replacements = {
  "\r\n" => "",
  "<p>" => "",
  "</p>" => "\n\n",
  "<br />" => "\n",
  "<strong>" => "*",
  "</strong>" => "*",
  "<em>" => "_",
  "</em>" => "_",
  "<s>" => "~",
  "</s>" => "~",
  "<blockquote>" => ">",
  "</blockquote>" => ">",
  "&" => "&amp;",
  "<" => "&lt;",
  ">" => "&gt;"
}

a = "<p>text</p> <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em>"

replacements.each do |find, replace|
  a.gsub!(find, replace)
end

a # => "text\n\n *bold* and _italic_"
```

Comment: Thanks Philipe, that would work, but I am looking for a way to do this with just one gsub call. I believe I am just missing the right regex.

Comment: Why? This is simpler, most likely faster, and easier to maintain than a regex.

Comment: Very possible. Honestly, both answers are correct and yours is indeed easier to maintain. So I'll accept your "possible duplicate" as a solution and mention to whoever reads this in the future that both answers here are acceptable. Thanks again.

Comment: Agreed, it's probably a LOT faster. A string search in much faster than an unanchored pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single call, regex is `/<[^>]+>|[<>&]/`

```
a = "<p>text</p> <strong>bold</strong> and <em>italic</em> & <>"
a.gsub(/(<[^>]+>|[<>&])/, replacements)
# => "text\n\n *bold* and _italic_ &amp; &lt;&gt;"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/M8ZC4e/1)

> `String#gsub(pattern, hash) → new_str`
>   If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string. [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-gsub)

Regex explanation:

- `<[^>]+>` matches HTML tags - you first match `<`, then one or multiple characters that are not `>` with `[^>]+` and then `>`
- `[<>&]` matches special single occurrences of special characters like `<`, `>` or `&`

That said, regex is not the best tool to process HTML, it's better to use HTML parser (e.g. Nokogiri).

Comment: Mrzasa, this works, thanks for you detailed explanation. I believe you have one mistake when you write "then > * [<>&]" should be "then > | [<>&]", right? How would you do the above with nokogiri? would it be cleaner?, and would it work faster and require less resources? What would be the benefits? Thanks again.

Comment: I messed with list formatting, fixed. Thanks @Ben :)